# more examples of reducing relative clauses into an adverb/adverbial phrase

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

Here's a sentence with a relative clause:

> The man who is upstairs knows all about the mystery.

It is possible to reduce the relative clause as such:

> the man **upstairs** knows all about the mystery.

the portion of the text above in bold is an adverb. I.E. the relative clause got reduced to an adverb (if we had a preposition then the end result would have been a prepositional phrase, which there are plenty of examples for online). I have been trying to find examples similar to the one above to no avail (to reiterate, examples without preposition). Could anyone supply more sentences like that?

Comment: Which bit is in bold? :)

Comment: "Upstairs" in your example is not an adverb, but an adjective modifying "man". Adverbs don't post-modify nouns. "Upstairs" is not a 'reduced' relative clause, but simply a post-head modifier, so we have a noun phrase, "the man", which has "man" as head word modified by the adjective "upstairs". Note that modern grammar classifies "upstairs" as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ it is according Viewpoin2 Unit2 lesson A

Comment: I don't agree with them. Adverbs don't normally modify nouns.